# How can I add 2 error messages in one box?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I am trying to do some form validation with this plugin http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

Right now I have it like this:
[image]

with this code:

```
    .row
        .form-group
            label(for="firstName") First Name*
            input(required type="text" id="firstName" data-error="We can't verify your name.")

            .help-block.with-errors         

        .form-group
            label(for="lastName") Last Name*
            input(required type="text" id="lastName" data-error="We can't verify your last name.")
            .help-block.with-errors
```

But I need to be like this according to the designers:

[image]

I am trying to do it with this code:

```
    .row.form-group
        .col-xs-12.col-sm-6
            label(for="firstName") First Name TEST*
            input(required type="text" id="firstName" data-error="We can't verify your name.")
        .col-xs-12.col-sm-6
            label(for="lastName") Last Name TEST*
            input(required type="text" id="lastName" data-error="We can't verify your last name.")

        .help-block.with-errors.full
```

but I am getting only the last error message:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Since you're using bootstrap, I'm assuming you've made your site responsive. In the event that you shrink the screen size to where it needs to become a vertical form, how do you want to handle a single box? Despite all your pictures, there's still not enough info.

Comment: @krillgar look at the second image. In the first and last name are errors since they are blank. And only one message it's been displayed. I need both error messages in that same box.

Comment: So when Last Name and its input wrap below First Name, you'll have a single box below Last Name, but nothing under First Name. That could cause problems if the user has to scroll to see it. Is that something you're willing to live with? That's why the convention is to typically have a single message associated with a single input.